# How to tell if MemberInfo is internal

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, internal

What is the quick test to determine if an instance of `MemberInfo` is internal ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to tell if MemberInfo is internal?

You can't because the question doesn't actually make sense.

A member info could be representing a property, and properties do not have an accessibility. (The getter and setter have an accessibility, but since they can be different, the property does not have an accessibility.)

Since there are members that do not have accessibility, there is no way to determine the accessibility of a member just from a MemberInfo. You'll need to turn it into a FieldInfo or TypeInfo or whatever it actually is and then ask that object what the accessibility is. (And of course if it is a PropertyInfo then you'll have to figure out whether you're interested in the getter or the setter and get the method info associated with it.)

Comment: very helpful thanks.  Is [`IsAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isassembly(v=VS.100).aspx) the correct property?

Comment: @smartcaveman: Yes, "assembly" is how Reflection refers to the accessibility that C# calls "internal" and VB calls "Friend". Note that a "protected internal"/"Protected Friend" field will *not* return true for IsAssembly. Read the MSDN documentation for the details.